# How to handle " https://gxxxx.com/xxxxx/xxxx.git: cannot open git-upload-pack" under Eclipse?

Tags: git, github

I am not able to clone a Git repository using eclipse. I get the below Error:

> https://gxxxx.com/xxxxx/xxxx.git: cannot open git-upload-pack"

Stack Trace:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://gitlab.com/induction/trainingplan.git: cannot open git-upload-pack
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.call(LsRemoteCommand.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.ListRemoteOperation.run(ListRemoteOperation.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.SourceBranchPage$8.run(SourceBranchPage.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://gitlab.com/induction/trainingplan.git: cannot open git-upload-pack
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.call(LsRemoteCommand.java:175)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: gitlab.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown 

    Source)
```

What can be done to cure the situation?

Answer (score 3):

The actual cause hides behind:

> Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: gitlab.com

This is telling you that you have been offline in the moment you tried to resolve the DNS of [gitlab.com](http://gitlab.com) OR that your local Internet (gateway or DNS servers) configuration is faulty / not working correctly.

Reconnect to the Internet (or check Proxy settings) and try again to checkout the desired git repository.

Hope it helps.